# DatabaseError at /admin/core/profile/add/ No exception message supplied

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-admin, djongo

I am building class models using Django and mongodb is connected to my server successfully.

When I create User account as UserAdmin, I can create and save new data and everything is snyc to my database.

However, when UserAdmin or superuser tried to create a Profile, which is built by one to one relationship, I got this error.

Local testing : ok
Deployed app : Cause this error

```
DatabaseError at /admin/core/userprofile/add/
No exception message supplied
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://csit-314-cinema-booking-system.vercel.app/admin/core/userprofile/add/
Django Version: 4.1.8
Exception Type: DatabaseError
Exception Location: /var/task/djongo/cursor.py, line 81, in fetchone
Raised during:  django.contrib.admin.options.add_view
Python Executable:  /var/lang/bin/python3.9
Python Version: 3.9.16
Python Path:    
['/var/task',
 '/opt/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
 '/opt/python',
 '/var/runtime',
 '/var/lang/lib/python39.zip',
 '/var/lang/lib/python3.9',
 '/var/lang/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
 '/opt/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
 '/opt/python']
```

This is my code.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser):
    ROLE = (
        ('UserAdmin', 'UserAdmin'),
        ('CinemaManager', 'CinemaManager'),
        ('Customer', 'Customer'),
        ('CinemaOwner', 'CinemaOwner'),
    )

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ROLE, default='Customer')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dob = models.DateField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    loyalty_points = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    
    # add any additional fields you want for the user profile here
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User, UserProfile

class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

I tried to fix this error by downgrading `django` and `djongo`, but *local testing worked well* but server got crashed. So downgrading the package is not a solution.

How can I fix this database error? Please lmk if u need more information.